# Why does the Google Geocode API return different coordinates for Localities and Localities+ZIP (same place)?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, geocoding

In most, if not all countries, each locality (address_components - "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]) has at least one Postal code, bigger cities have multiple Postal codes (address_components - "types" : [ "postal_code" ]). 
But most Localities only have one Postal Code.
When using the Google Geocode API for Localities with only one Postal Code, the locality (Example: "richterswil") and the locality plus the corresponding postal code (Example: "8805+richterswil) return different coordinates. This is unexpected in my oppinion, and makes certain tasks much more complicated 
than they should be (think of finding the coordinates for a place the users enters - some will include the Postal Code, and some will not, which causes different coordinates for essentially the exact same thing). What's the reason for this and how to work arround it properly (Get the same coordinates for all cases without requesting the Postal code in the input field)?

-I have found that when not including the Postal Code in the Geocode API call, the coordinates of the searched place are exactly at the same location where google displays the Name of the Locality on the Map (label). 
-When including the Postal code, the coordinates seem randomly shifted for 500-1000 Meters.

I have used these API Calls to experiment (Add your own API Key):

1. No Postal Code:

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=richterswil&components=country:CH&key=YOUR_API_KEY&language=de

2. Postal Code Included:

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=8805+richterswil&components=country:CH&key=YOUR_API_KEY&language=de

1. Response (No Postal Code):

```
{
   "results" : [
      {
         "address_components" : [
            {
               "long_name" : "Richterswil",
               "short_name" : "Richterswil",
               "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Horgen",
               "short_name" : "Horgen",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_2", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Zürich",
               "short_name" : "ZH",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Schweiz",
               "short_name" : "CH",
               "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
            }
         ],
         "formatted_address" : "Richterswil, Schweiz",
         "geometry" : {
            "bounds" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 47.2335482,
                  "lng" : 8.7409239
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 47.18228,
                  "lng" : 8.661769999999999
               }
            },
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 47.2053892,
               "lng" : 8.7070691
            },
            "location_type" : "APPROXIMATE",
            "viewport" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 47.2335482,
                  "lng" : 8.7409239
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 47.18228,
                  "lng" : 8.661769999999999
               }
            }
         },
         "place_id" : "ChIJO0JjJ6CxmkcRLdEGdhgDTXg",
         "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

2. Response (Postal Code Included):

```
{
   "results" : [
      {
         "address_components" : [
            {
               "long_name" : "8805",
               "short_name" : "8805",
               "types" : [ "postal_code" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Richterswil",
               "short_name" : "Richterswil",
               "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Horgen",
               "short_name" : "Horgen",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_2", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Zürich",
               "short_name" : "ZH",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Schweiz",
               "short_name" : "CH",
               "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
            }
         ],
         "formatted_address" : "8805 Richterswil, Schweiz",
         "geometry" : {
            "bounds" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 47.2201589,
                  "lng" : 8.713399599999999
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 47.1962357,
                  "lng" : 8.679173199999999
               }
            },
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 47.2097073,
               "lng" : 8.696259999999999
            },
            "location_type" : "APPROXIMATE",
            "viewport" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 47.2201589,
                  "lng" : 8.713399599999999
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 47.1962357,
                  "lng" : 8.679173199999999
               }
            }
         },
         "place_id" : "ChIJ-Ub3o--xmkcRNqm0YtWPm1U",
         "types" : [ "postal_code" ]
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

Comment: As a user, if I see an input field that instructs me to enter a city name, I will enter a city name, not a zip code...

Answer (score 0):

This is because localities and postal_codes have different territories, they are not the same place. You can check this in Google Maps.

[No Postal Code](https://www.google.com/maps/place/Richterswil,+Switzerland/@47.1945971,8.6729209,13.59z/data=!4m5!3m4!1s0x479ab1a02763423b:0x784d03187606d12d!8m2!3d47.2053892!4d8.7070691)

[Postal Code Included](https://www.google.com/maps/place/8805+Richterswil,+Switzerland/@47.2027139,8.6775359,13.85z/data=!4m5!3m4!1s0x479ab1efa3f746f9:0x559b8fd562b4a936!8m2!3d47.2097073!4d8.69626)

> But most Localities only have one Postal Code.

I dont think this is a good assumption for your code as there are alot of countries with multiple postal codes in 1 locality.

This is why the `postcode_localities[]` field exists in the [Geocoding API response](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding#GeocodingResults).

As for your requests :

> No Postal Code:
>   https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=richterswil&components=country:CH&key=YOUR_API_KEY&language=de

This one points the coordinates at the APPROXIMATE center of "Richterswil, Schweiz", where it is marked according to the map, see how it is on top of the label :

[image: https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/utils/geocoder/#place_id%3DChIJO0JjJ6CxmkcRLdEGdhgDTXg]

> Postal Code Included:
>   https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=8805+richterswil&components=country:CH&key=YOUR_API_KEY&language=de

For this one, it is pointing at the center of the postal code, shown in the google maps link above